# how search multiple name from same table using join query

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables. In first table

```
id  book_name   date
--------------------------
2    php       12-10-2015
3   java       12-10-2015
---------------------------
```

in the second table

```
id  book_1  book_2   
-------------------
12   2       3
------------------
```

now what will be the SQL query for viewing like this when search in SQL

```
id  book_1  book_2
---------------------
12   php    java
---------------------
```

Comment: To format as `code`, select the text and press `ctrl-k`  or add 4 spaces before each line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for **[JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)**.

You `JOIN` `table2` with `table1` twice, using `ALIAS` to difference between them.

```
SELECT T2.id, A.book_name, B.book_name
FROM Table2 T2
JOIN Table1 A
  ON T2.book_1   = A.id  
JOIN Table1 B
  ON T2.book_2   = B.id
```

Comment: Remember accept this answer as the correct one, and upvote when you have that privilege